# DatePicker SelectedDateChanged event

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, datetimepicker

In my Silverlight project in XAML I have created a window containing the DatePicker control. Then I set in the constructor of the window SelectedDate value and define callback function for selecteddatechanged event.
Why is this callback function called immediatelly after selecteddate is changed in the constructor?
 I thought it will be only called after some user change the date and not immediatelly after first initialization in the constructor.

```
public MyWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.datePicker.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
    this.datePicker.SelectedDateChanged += new EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(datePicker_SelectedDateChanged);
}

void datePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why? Put in a break point and check the sender object. That might give you a clue to why something is triggering the change event.

As to a resolution, if the sender is unique enough, code could written to ignore that sender; hence solving the problem.

Comment: public MyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.datePicker.SelectedDate = new DateTime(1950,1,1);
        this.datePicker.SelectedDateChanged += new EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(datePicker_SelectedDateChanged);
}

    void datePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // on breakpoint sender is 1.1.1950 00:00:00
    }

Comment: can the initialization of the date to 1950 happen before the call to InitializeComponent()?

Comment: Did you mean this?
`public MyWindow() 
{ 
this.datePicker.SelectedDate = new DateTime(1950,1,1);     
InitializeComponent(); 
this.datePicker.SelectedDateChanged += new EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs>(datePicker_SelectedDateChanged);  }`
but this cause null reference exception...

Comment: Maybe try using Teleriks or Component1s date pickers to see if that works out better.